# How to apply a Sub Procedure to a sub-string variable in other code?

Tags: excel, vba

Given this code:

```
OCAddress1 = Split(Target.Value, vbLf)
Target.Value = OCAddress1(0) 'Address
Target.Offset(, 2).Value = Split(OCAddress1(1), ", ")(0) 'City
OCStateZip = Split(Split(OCAddress1(1), ", ")(1), " ")
Target.Offset(, 3).Value = Replace(Split(OCAddress1(1), ", ")(1), OCStateZip(UBound(OCStateZip)), "") 'State
Target.Offset(, 4).Value = OCStateZip(UBound(OCStateZip)) 'Zip
```

And a separate Sub Procedure named `Sub StateFullName(ByVal Target As Range)`

How do I apply the `StateFullName` Sub Procedure to specifically this line of code:

```
    Target.Offset(, 3).Value = Replace(Split(OCAddress1(1), ", ")(1), OCStateZip(UBound(OCStateZip)), "") 'State
```

How do I ensure that when the code at the very top runs, the Sub Procedure named `Sub StateFullName(ByVal Target As Range)` is automatically applied specifically to the single line of code above.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You don't "apply" subs or functions to lines of code. You call the subs or functions, sometimes with arguments, and they return some value. It's difficult to tell what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: If you want to apply it to the value in `Target.Offset(, 3)` you can call the procedure like `StateFullName Target.Offset(, 3)` in a line right after `Target.Offset(, 3).Value = Replace(Split(OCAddress1(1), ", ")(1), OCStateZip(UBound(OCStateZip)), "")`. If that is not what you wanted please [edit] your question and add the code of the procedure `StateFullName` and tell what you expect to get as a result.